# Looping a function over Lists in R

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have a list of samples, each of varying lengths. I need to compare sample means (using a Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test) for all samples in the list. Current code is as follows:

```
wilcox.v = list() ##This creates the list of samples
for (i in df){
    treat = list(i$treatment)
    wilcox.v = c(wilcox.v,treat)
}
###This *should* iterate over all items in the list
wilcox = sapply(wilcox.v, function(i){ wilcox.test(as.numeric(wilcox.v[i,]), as.numeric(wilcox.v[-i,]), exact = FALSE)$p.value
})
```

I'd like to have the function return a vector of p-values, so that the broader function can re-sample if necessary.

The problem seems to lie in the need to compare a sample mean to all other sample means in the list.

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this (and I think it has something to do with calling indicies correctly), but I'm not sure!

Comment: `sapply` does iterate over all element of `wilcox.v`. Each element of `wilcox.v` is handed off to your function and passed to the argument `i`. So `i` will be each successive element of `wilcox.v`. You seem to have written your function as though `i` was simply an integer index.

Answer (score 0):

AS joran said, you wrote your apply function a little wonky. There are two ways you can fis this.

1. Modify it so `i` is in fact an index reference:

   ```
   wilcox = sapply(1:length(wilcox.v)
              ,function(i){ wilcox.test(as.numeric(wilcox.v[[i]])
              ,as.numeric(wilcox.v[[-i]]), exact = FALSE)$p.value
              })
   ```
2. modify your function so it appropriately treats `i` as a list element. I'll leave this as an exercise to you (primarily since I don't want to deal with the `wilcox.v[-i,]` term.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! This is the solution I ended up using. It's hardly elegant but it gets the job done.

```
mannwhit = vector()
for (i in mannwhit.v){
    for (j in mannwhit.v){
        if (identical(i,j) == FALSE){
            p.val = wilcox.test(i, j, paired=FALSE)$p.value
            mannwhit = c(mannwhit, p.val)
        }
    }
}
```